# Excel Comparing Cells in Different Sheets

Tags: excel

i have this problem2 days now if anyone could help me

sheet 1
col A       col B       C(price)        D          E(barcode)(1000 entries)

sheet 2
col A       col B       C(price)    D  E  F  G     I(barcode)(10000 entries)

i want to make a formula that compares col E(sheet 1) and col I (sheet 2) and if they are the same the result is to replace the price of col C(sheet 1) with the price of col C(sheet 2).

if that is not possible, then to show the price of col C(sheet 2) to a new Col F of sheet 1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Index and Match combo to get the price from sheet 2

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!E2,Sheet2!I:I,0))
```

To make sure that no #N/As are displayed, just add Iferror like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!E2,Sheet2!I:I,0)),"")
```